# Failed to import bridging header xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, cocoapods

I wanted to use one of my previous swift project for the current project. So I renamed it. Then reinstall all pod files. Then I got the following error. 
[image]

Also Checked the header file path in Build settings>Swift compiler code generation>Objective C Bridging Header. It's fine there. But when I try to build it gives me that error. Is it the paypal sdk or something else?? The sdk was installed correctly via pod install. Any help would be appreciated. I'm Using xcode 6.4 & swift 1.2
Also I got some bizarre warning after removing & reinstalling all the pods.
[image]
is that going to be any problem??

Comment: check out this question: [a quick solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046676/file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-frameworks-into-s/34046677#34046677)

Answer (score 1):

Although this post is quite old, someone can have the same issue.
Here is a possible answer.
Check "manually" if those files are included in your project, from "TARGET"/"Build Phases"/"Compiles Sources".

PS: renaming projects is not as easy as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

the issue here not from import bridge , its because complier cant see your PaypalMobile make sure its included Target Project -- >Build Phases --> Compile Sources -- > add .m file of all needed files to be include in project